# JQuery to find next class in unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using JQuery/Ajax for some functionality on my site.  Currently I have a left side that displays an unordered list and each list element has a class of something like shop-thumb, Whenever some clicks on a shop-thumb then on the right that content is loaded with Ajax.

Now I want to incorporate a next/previous button so users can click next (from the right side) and the next list item is loaded with the ajax changing the content on the right.

Here is a really basic version of what I am working with:

```
<div class="thumbs">
    <ul class="products">
        <li class="shop-thumb"><a href="www.google.com/123"><img src="www.google.com/image1" /></a></li>
        <li class="shop-thumb"><a href="www.google.com/456"><img src="www.google.com/image2" /></a></li>
        <li class="shop-thumb"><a href="www.google.com/789"><img src="www.google.com/image3" /></a></li>
        <li class="shop-thumb"><a href="www.google.com/101112"><img src="www.google.com/image4" /></a></li>
        <li class="shop-thumb"><a href="www.google.com/131415"><img src="www.google.com/image5" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="paginate">
    <div class="prev">Prev</div> | <div class="next">Next</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
<!-- Ajax comes in here -->
</div>
```

Here is what I have in my JQuery/Ajax calls -- Everything is working fine except the .next click function:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var defaultValue = $("ul.products li.shop-thumb a:first").attr("href");

    $(".main").load(defaultValue);

  $("ul.products li.shop-thumb a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".main").load(addressValue);

  });

  $(".next").click(function() {
      $("ul.products").next();
      var newValue = $("ul.products .shop-thumb a").attr("href");
      $(".main").load(newValue);
  });

});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated on how I can achieve this next/previous functionality.  Thought I should be using `.next()`, `.find()` or `.nextAll`

If you wouldn't mind throwing me a bone and showing me an example so I can see where and what I did wrong.

Comment: With so much code, you should make a fiddle.  Also `defaultValue` is usually a element property, which you might want to think about not using as a variable name.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of `.next()`. What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: And `ul.products` doesn't have anything after it. It seems like you have absolutely no idea what `.next()` does, you're just guessing that it does something related to what your `Next` button needs because they have similar names.

Comment: Thanks vol7ron, I didn't even think about using a fiddle.   @Barmar, You are right, this is my first time implementing .next() and I was reading about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_next.asp  but it was unclear and after several attempts I reached out to the community here for some advice :)

Comment: I don't generally recommend using w3schools, but it seems pretty clear: _The next() method **returns** the next **sibling** element of the selected element._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a marker for the current item to find out what is the next item. Once you find the next item, you can just fire the click event on that item to invoke the handler

You can use a class like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("ul.products li.shop-thumb a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".main").load(addressValue);

        //remove the active class from previous item
        $("ul.products li.active").removeClass('active');
        //add the active class to the current li element
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    });

    $(".next").click(function () {
        //find the next item and trigger the click event
        $("ul.products li.active").next().find('a').trigger('click');
    });

    //default loading
    $("ul.products li.shop-thumb a:first").click();

});
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, exactly what I was looking for…  Quick question, how would I incorporate the previous button click functionality?  Could I use your same logic like this: '$(".prev").click(function () {
  $("ul.products li.active").prev().find('a').trigger('click');
 });'

Comment: I guess I answered my question with that last comment, thanks again for your help, really helped me understand my question.